# Maps to $K(\pi,1)$ spaces from manifolds with $S^1$-action

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

Suppose $M$ is a *connected* smooth manifold with a smooth $S^1$-action that fixes a point in $M$. Let $X$ be a $K(\pi,1)$-space and let $\varphi: M\to X$ be a continuous map.

**Question.** How to prove that $\varphi$ can be homotoped to a map $\varphi': M\to X$ that sends each orbit of the $S^1$ action to a point in $X$?

I would be grateful for a short proof or a reference.

**Remark.** I can prove the statement when $X$ is a negatively curved manifold, but I am confident that the statement holds as well when $X$ is $K(\pi,1)$.

Comment: What if one orbit is sent by $\varphi$ to a nontrivial conjugacy class in $\pi$?

Comment: All the orbits will be sent to contractible loops since there is one orbit (a fixed point) that is sent to a point.

Comment: First, please add connectivity assumption for $M$. Then, can't you just argue that if the $S^1$-action is reasonably nice (say, smooth, on a smooth manifold) then the projection map $M\to Y=M/S^1$ induces an isomorphism of $\pi_1$'s (since each $S^1$-orbit is null-homotopic in $M$)? This part might be in Bredon's book "Compact transformation groups". Then use Whitehead's theorem for the maps $Y\to X$ (again, assuming that $X$ is, say, a CW complex).

Comment: Misha, thanks for the remark! Unfortunately $\pi_1(M)$ does not need to be equal to $\pi_1(Y)$. Indeed, even in the case when $M$ is a $3$-dimensional manifold, the quotient $M/S^1=Y$ can be a topological $2$-disc with non-trivial orbi-structure. Then $\pi_1(Y)=0$, but $\pi_1(M)$ is huge

Comment: You have to use the existence of a global fixed point. In the 3d examples that I know this is not the case.

Comment: Misha, what about the following example: start with the $S^1$ action on $S^3$ that fixes a circle pointwise. Then the quotient $S^3/S^1$ is a disc. Now take a connected sum along an $S^1$ fiber of this $S^3$ with a Seifert manifold $N$ such that $N/S^1$ is $S^2$. The resulting sum of $S^3$ and $N$ can not be $S^3$ (since all $S^1$ actions on $S^3$ are easy to classify). So the resulting sum has non-trivial $\pi_1$ contradicting to what you claim.

Comment: As soon as you have an example in which $\pi_1(M)\to \pi_1(M/S^1)$ is not injective, you have a counterexample. Let $\pi$ be $\pi_1(M)$ and let $M\to K(\pi,1)$ induce isomorphism in $\pi_1$.

Comment: Thanks Tom. This indeed answers the question in negative, I believe.

Comment: It seems one issue with this approach is that we cannot easily guarantee $X$ is a manifold. Is there a nice counter-example where $X$ is a compact manifold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to explain why the answer to the question is negative in general, following the suggestion of Tom Godwillie (however see **PS** for a positive answer if $dimX<\infty$)

Let us note first that there is an $S^1$-action on $\mathbb RP^2=M$ such that the quotient is a the segment.

Now, apply the idea of Tom Goodwille. Namely take $\Gamma=\mathbb Z_2$, and consider the inclusion $\mathbb RP^2\to \mathbb RP^{\infty}=K(\mathbb Z_2,1)$ that induces an isomorphism on $\pi_1$. Clearly, this map is not contractible, so it gives a counterexample to the claim in the question.

**PS**. However, using the remark of Misha it is also possible to prove that the answer to the question is positive in the case when the group $\pi=\Gamma=\pi_1(X)$ has no torsion elements. In particular, it holds when $X$ is finite-dimensional.

**Sketch proof.** Denote $M/S^1$ by $Y$ and let $p$ be the projection map. I claim that *the kernel of the homomorphism $\phi^M_Y:\pi_1(M)\to \pi_1(Y)$ induced by $p$ is generated by torsion elements*. Since $\Gamma$ has no torsion elements, it follows that any homomorphism $\phi^M_X:\pi_1(M)\to \Gamma$ factors through a homomorphism $\phi^M_Y$, i.e. there exists $\phi^Y_X:\pi_1(Y)\to \pi_1(X)$ such that  $$\phi^M_X=\phi^Y_X\circ\phi^M_Y.$$

Now, since $X$ is aspherical, the homomorphism $\phi^Y_X$ is induced by a map $\psi: Y\to X$. Finally note that the original map $\varphi: M\to X$ and the composed map $\psi\circ p$ are homotopic, since they induce the same homomorphism on $\pi_1(M)$.

Answer (score 1):

See this paper, theorem 3.5

*Gottlieb, Daniel H.; Lee, Kyung B.; Ozaydin, Murad*, [**Compact group actions and maps into $K(\pi,1)$-spaces**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2000419), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 287, 419-429 (1985). [ZBL0524.57026](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0524.57026).

Comment: @aglearner Oops! Reading comprehension issues... I will look more.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately this answer doesn't address the question...